# Total sum for an object property value in a list using a lambda function

Tags: c#, list, properties, lambda

I have the following: `List<OutputRow>` which contains a number of `OutputRow` objects.

I am wondering if there is a way for me to use a lambda function on the list to return the total sum of the values of a certain propertyX on each OutputRow object in the list.

Example list:

```
OutputRow.propertyX = 4  
OutputRow.propertyX = 6  
OutputRow.propertyX = 5
```

return 15

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Test data**

```
var ls=new List<OutputRow>();
ls.Add(new OutputRow(){propertyX=4});
ls.Add(new OutputRow(){propertyX=6});
ls.Add(new OutputRow(){propertyX=5});
```

**Lambda**

```
var total= ls.Sum(x=>x.propertyX);
```

Answer (score 3):

SOmething like this:

```
var yourSum = yourOutputRowList.Sum(x => x.propertyX);
```